# AND Operator in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

2 Node is UP and Running and I want to get alerts if both nodes get down, for that I am writing queries in Prometheus but getting an error

> up{service="brokerA-metrics"} and {service="brokerB-metrics"} == 1

**I am getting NO DATA POINT**

> up({service="brokerA-metrics"} and {service="brokerB-metrics"}) == 1

**Error executing query: parse error at char 4: unknown function with name "up"**

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

> (up{service="brokerA-metrics"} + ignoring(service) {service="brokerB-metrics"}) == 0

Or

> ...) < 1

if you want to trigger alert if just one node is down

Comment: Thanks for your response but still getting errors:-

`Error executing query: many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side`

and I don't want to trigger an alert if just one node is down; **I want to trigger if both are down.**

Comment: do you have more labels in these metrics besides service? this idea should work, i tried it on mine metrics.. if you have more labels, add them in ignoring

Answer (score 0):

The `and` operator returns time series on the left side if there are matching time series with the same set of labels on the right side according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

The `(up{service="brokerA-metrics"}==0) and (up{service="brokerB-metrics"}==0)` query returns `no data`, because all the time series on the left side of `and` have `service="brokerA-metrics"` label, while all the time series on the right side of `and` have `service="brokerB-metrics"` label. These labels do not match, so the query returns `no data`.

This can be fixed by using `on()` or `ignoring()` modifiers, which limit the set of labels, which are taken into account when searching for time series pairs with identical labelsets. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for details. For example, the following query ignores all the labels when searching for time series pairs with identical labelsets:

```
(up{service="brokerA-metrics"}==0) and on() (up{service="brokerB-metrics"}==0)
```